# Can I schedule a mail delivery without using GAS trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, gmail

Gmail has the option to schedule mailings from the application.

Is this option implemented in `GmailApp.sendEmail()`?

I don't want to use Google Apps Script triggers, I want to use the option given by the `GmailApp`

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use triggers, though? Create a self-removing one and voila, you curcumvented the issue with hard cap on number of triggers. One day we might get the ability to schedule, but alas...

Answer (score 2):

*Is this option implemented in GmailApp.sendEmail()?*

ATTOW, no, please see the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

*Bonus: can I schedule this using Gmail API?*

ATTOW, also no, see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)

**Workaround**

I understand that you don't want to use triggers, but until the feature is implemented, you can emulate scheduling logic using a trigger and `PropertiesService` (or a database of your choosing if you need to store larger emails). Here is a working sample of how you may achieve this (I opted to use a 1 minute trigger, but in real world it might be more pragmatic to use a higher delay between checks):

```
const sendScheduledEmail = () => {
    const propertyName = "emailSchedule";

    const store = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

    const savedSchedule = store.getProperty(propertyName) || "[]";

    /** @type {emailConfig[]} */
    const parsed = JSON.parse(savedSchedule);

    if(!parsed.length) {
        console.log("Nothing to send");
        return;
    }

    const currentDT = Date.now();

    const leftToSend = parsed.filter(emailConfig => {

        const { 
            delay, 
            subject, 
            recipient, 
            body, 
            options 
        } = emailConfig;

        if (currentDT > delay) {
            GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });

    store.setProperty(propertyName, JSON.stringify(leftToSend));
};

/**
 * @typedef {object} delayedConfig
 * @property {number} delay
 * 
 * @typedef {object} commonEmailConfig
 * @property {string} body
 * @property {string} recipient
 * @property {string} subject
 * @property {GoogleAppsScript.Gmail.GmailAdvancedOptions} options
 * 
 * @typedef {commonEmailConfig & delayedConfig} emailConfig
 * 
 * @param {...emailConfig} configs 
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
const scheduleEmailSend = (...configs) => {

    try {

        const now = Date.now();

        const normalizedDelayConfigs = configs.map(config => {
            const { delay } = config;
            config.delay = now + delay;
            return config;
        });

        const checkTriggerName = "sendScheduledEmail", propertyName = "emailSchedule";

        const triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

        const [trigger] = triggers.filter(trig => trig.getHandlerFunction() === checkTriggerName);

        !trigger && ScriptApp.newTrigger(checkTriggerName).timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();

        const store = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

        const savedSchedule = store.getProperty(propertyName) || "[]";

        /** @type {emailConfig[]} */
        const parsed = JSON.parse(savedSchedule);

        parsed.push(...normalizedDelayConfigs);

        store.setProperty(propertyName, JSON.stringify(parsed));


    } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

---

Google is already aware of the feature, please join others on the already opened [request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140922183) - it will have a better chance of being introduced.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for the answer, I have supported the option requested in the thread you have marked

Comment: Thank you for providing feedback to both answers, Fernando - a rare sight these days. Please, consider accepting one of them (or maybe someone will come up with a workaround we could not think of)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, creating the delay had already been thought through and implemented. He understood that it was logically possible with triggers.
But you know that the option to do it with the Gmail delay is the best option even if you want to do a mailmerge, and asking Google to implement it is important. Let's see if among several, we succeed.


Thanks for everything.

Comment: Sure, just added it in case someone who stumbles onto a question needs a workaround - unfortunately, sometimes feature requests aren't processed for years, although this is such a useful and demanded feature, so I wouldn't be surprized if it will be added in one of the upcoming updates to GAS platform. Let's hope it will happen sooner than later

Comment: I understand the reason for your explanation. Many times these publications have served me for years.

It would be great if the GAS platform added it.

If you have knowledge of it, I would appreciate it if you would let me know

I am completely an amatter in programming and only use it when I need it for some situation at work.

Thanks for your dedication and help. It's nice to meet people who help like you online.

Comment: @FernandoMollatPardo - likewise, appreciated that you give feedback to users and give your thoughts on the matter - not a very common practice currently, I must sadly admit. You can click "follow" on either mine or ale13's (or any other that comes along) answer and will receive updates when the post changes / has any traction - I at least tend to revisit answers in light of new info if I recall that I answered something related (or a passer by will comment / edit that the feature is up), so do a lot of us

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the only option available of scheduling the sending of an email is by using the triggers.

What you can do instead is to file a **Feature Request** for the Gmail API using Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=824107) and provide the details needed regarding this.

Comment: Thanks Ale13, I preferred to follow Oleg's advice, which being similar to the one you are commenting on, allows us to be more of those who request it.